# User should be able to say the number of times within which image cannot be repeated

Tags: c#

I have a set of images in a folder and I want to display images randomly in a condition for which user should be able to say the number of times within which image cannot be repeated. i.e if there are 10 images and user inputs 3 then it should display other images (except those 3 which were displayed recently) which were not displayed recently in an random order.

Comment: Why don't you post what you have now and what specifically you're running into with issues? As it is now, it sounds like you want someone to write something from scratch.

Comment: What have you got so far? We're here to help, but not to write your project for you.

Comment: Hey, that's just an algorithmic problem. If the guy has problems with designing the algorithm, how would he be able to write any code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a `List` with all filenames in it. Let `n` be the minimal count of images that shall lie between two displays of the same image.

```
var list = new List<string>();
// Fill list with all filenames ...
```

Then just select one of the images from the range `[0..len(List)-n]` randomly like

```
// Initialization of random number generator just once...
var rand = new Random();
// ...

var index = rand.Next(list.Count - n);
var nextImage = list[index];
```

Now, Remove the image and put it at the end of the list.

```
list.RemoveAt(index);
list.Add(nextImage);
```

`nextImage` now contains your next image.

Comment: Considering the less amount of details/effort put forth by the OP in posting the question, this seems to be the most plausible answer. Hope the OP finds this post useful. +1 :)